# How to i test invalid input in jMock?

Tags: java, junit, jmock

I want to test for invalid input for the method calculateChange() in Sale class.
How do i verify the expectation?

Is it correct by checking whether the value return from calculatechange() is null to verify that
the input is invalid?

Below is my initialization for the test.

```
 public void testCalculateChange() {
            final char paidAmount = 'a';
            Sale.totalPrice = 28.50;

    }
```

Below is my Sale Class.

```
public class Sale {
    public static double totalPrice=0;
    private static double change;


    private Sale() {}

    public static double calculateChange(double paidAmount) {
        change = paidAmount - totalPrice;            
        return change;
    }
}
```

Comment: The return value of `calculateChange()` cannot be `null` since the type `double` is a primitive type, not a reference type for objects. There is no code in your `calculateChange()` method which checks that anything is correct or incorrect. How do you check for invalid input and what do you want to do?

Comment: Yeah, i didn't include the code to check whether it's correct or not because i do not know how to check(code) for it. I want to prove that, by inputting an invalid input, let's say a symbol, will fail the test. How do i do that?

Comment: @Progman sorry, forgot to notify you

Comment: What `calculateChange()` should do on an invalid input is your choice. First you have to define what invalid input is for your `calculateChange()` method. You have a `double` argument `paidAmount` and a static field `totalPrice`. Depending on these values you might want to throw an `IllegalArgumentException`. Add javadocs to your `Sale` class to make it more clear what the class, fields and methods do and how they work.

Comment: @Progman owh ya.. never thought of using IllegalArgumentException.. Thanks for your help!!